# Like we have readFileSync function in node js, I need http.getSync - a wrapper for http.get() to make it sync

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make the implementation of this https.getSync the wrapper method, so that it calls the api synchronously, same like the readFileSync method which we use for reading file synchronously,

```
const https = require('https');
```

How should i implement this method -

```
https.getSync = (url) => {
    let data = '';
    https.get(url, resp => {

        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });
        resp.on('end', () => {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
    return data;
}
```

I want the below two calls to be made synchronously, without changing the below code where we are calling the getSync method. Here for this calling i don't want to use promises or callback.

```
let api1 =  https.getSync('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY');
let api2 = https.getSync('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=NNKOjkoul8n1CH18TWA9gwngW1s1SmjESPjNoUFo');
```

Comment: There's a good reason for this method being asynchronous. What you want to do is to block your server untill the http requests are done. That's probably not what you really want ..? If you can't handle asynchronity, learn it! You simply can't ignore it when you're working with node.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can use npm package `sync-request`.

It's quite simple.

```
var request = require('sync-request');
var res = request('GET', 'http://example.com');
console.log(res.getBody());
```

Here is the link: [sync-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request)

> **Read this also:**  *An announcement from the package, in case readers would think using it is a good idea. You should not be using this in a production application. In a node.js application you will find that you are completely unable to scale your server. In a client application you will find that sync-request causes the app to hang/freeze. Synchronous web requests are the number one cause of browser crashes.*

According to me also you should avoid making `http` sync request. Instead clear your concepts of using `callback, promise, async/await`.

Comment: That's correct. An announcement from the package, in case readers would think using it is a good idea. *You should not be using this in a production application. In a node.js application you will find that you are completely unable to scale your server. In a client application you will find that sync-request causes the app to hang/freeze. Synchronous web requests are the number one cause of browser crashes*

Comment: Yes, agree with @estus